# Yii2 Display Error Messages Inside Modal

Tags: php, modal-dialog, yii2

Here's how I implement my modal in my `index.php` **view**:

```
<?= Html::button(
    'Change Password',
    ['value' => Url::to(['changepassword']). '&id=' . $session['user_id'],
    'class' => 'btn btn-success',
        'id' => 'modButton'

    ]) ?>
<?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('message'); ?>
<?php
    Modal::begin(['id' => 'modal2']);
        echo "<div id='modContent'></div>";    
    Modal::end();
?>
```

And here is my modal form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('message'); ?>
</br>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['value' => '', 'style' => 'width: 300px;'])->label('New Password') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'ConfirmNewPassword')->passwordInput(['value' => '', 'style' => 'width: 300px;']) ?>    

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Change Password', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In my **controller** (just in case you'll be needing it):

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->password = sha1($model->password);
    if($model->password !== sha1($model->ConfirmNewPassword)){
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('message', "Passwords don't match!");
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
}
```

Every time I input an invalid password in my modal, the page redirects to the modal form in a separate page and there it displays the error message. I want that when the user inputs an invalid password, the modals stays with the error message somewhere inside it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you redirect to the "index" action if the password is not the same in Controller :

```
if($model->password !== sha1($model->ConfirmNewPassword)){
  Yii::$app->session->setFlash('message', "Passwords don't match!");
  return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Should becomes :

```
if($model->password !== sha1($model->ConfirmNewPassword)){
  Yii::$app->session->setFlash('message', "Passwords don't match!");
}
else {
  return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```